# AngularJS with JQuery response content inside div

Tags: angularjs

I use JQuery post to communicate with server, and show the response inside a div. The response is an AngularJS script, like

```html
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="formController" class="ng-scope">
  <form novalidate="" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName.x" class="ng-valid ng-dirty"><br>
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName.y" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <br><br>
  </form>
  <p class="ng-binding">form = {{user}}</p>
</div>
```

But it does not work. Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Comment: what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran it, it worked except:

1. You have double quotes after app. They're not necessary for the code to run.
2. User firstname is entered twice, which will create two text boxes, one under the other. Syntactically, you may want to re-name the second variable (user middle name?) since not many people have two first names.
3. You're printing form=user with the quote after binding. Take it out and form=user will stop printing itself on your screen. At least it did when I tried it.